# MySQL update value if condition

Tags: mysql, csv

Is it possible to update a value depending on a condition?

Example:
db-one

```
ID  Code    Brand   PN     Model
1   X62     Puma    x1234    
2   X62     Puma    x2345    
3   X63     Puma    x3456    
4   X63     Nike    x4567    
5   X62     Nike    x5678    
6   X62     Nike    x6789    
7   X63     Nike    x7890    
8   X63     Puma    x8901    
9   X62     Nike    x9012   
10  X62     Puma    x1234    
11  X62     Puma    x2345    
12  X63     Puma    x3456    
13  X63     Nike    x4567    
14  X62     Nike    x5678    
15  X62     Nike    x6789    
16  X63     Nike    x7890    
17  X63     Puma    x8901    
18  X62     Nike    x9012
```

And i have a List: db-update

```
PN      Model
x1234   9012
x2345   8901
x3456   7890
x4567   6789
x5678   5678
x6789   4567
x7890   3456
x8901   2345
x9012   1234
```

In this Example I want to import the second list so it will write the coresponding "Model" to the "PN" if it exists
This is how it should look in the end:
db-one

```
ID  Code    Brand   PN      Model
1   X62     Puma    x1234   9012
2   X62     Puma    x2345   8901
3   X63     Puma    x3456   7890
4   X63     Nike    x4567   6789
5   X62     Nike    x5678   5678
6   X62     Nike    x6789   4567
7   X63     Nike    x7890   3456
8   X63     Puma    x8901   2345
9   X62     Nike    x9012   1234
10  X62     Puma    x1234   9012
11  X62     Puma    x2345   8901
12  X63     Puma    x3456   7890
13  X63     Nike    x4567   6789
14  X62     Nike    x5678   5678
15  X62     Nike    x6789   4567
16  X63     Nike    x7890   3456
17  X63     Puma    x8901   2345
18  X62     Nike    x9012   1234
```

Comment: `update table t set t.model=csv.model where t.pn=csv.pn and csv.model <> ''`

Comment: A word of advice, don't ask for tools advice like you did at the very bottom.  It quickly turns into a closed question for opinion advice or off-topic resource or tool closure reason. Look into `LOAD DATA INFILE` of the csv, or import via phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If List is a table, you can do an UPDATE with a JOIN:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t JOIN list l
  ON t.PN = l.PN
SET
  t.model = l.model
```

if list is not a table, you could do multiple queries:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET model='1234' WHERE PN='x9012'
...
```

or you could use this:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t JOIN (
    SELECT 'x1234' PN, '9012' Model UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x2345' PN, '8901' Model UNION ALL
    ..etc...
  ) l
  ON t.PN = l.PN
SET
  t.model = l.model
```

Comment: I like the 'first make list a table' idea

Comment: Question: What if in my table PN i have multiple strings like: "x1234, x2345, x3456"
Is it possible to only find a partial string in thsi example "x1234" in the string and write the "model" in the column "model" ?

Comment: Maybe something like

UPDATE yourtable t JOIN list l ON t.PN LIKE l.`%PN%` SET t.model = l.model

Comment: @finua you could use FIND_IN_SET if values are a comma separated list of values: `UPDATE yourtable t JOIN list l ON FIND_IN_SET(t.PN, l.PN)>0 SET ...`

Comment: @fthiella and what if the string is seperrated by anything else? in my example its "x1234 / x2345 / x3456"

Comment: @finua you can use `FIND_IN_SET(t.PN, REPLACE(l.PN, ' / ', ''))` or just `WHERE t.PN LIKE CONCAT('%', l.PN, '%')` (could fail sometimes...)

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly, you swaped the t.pn and the i.pn in your first query ^^